# Extract the contents of a string between two string delimiters using match in C#

Tags: c#, regex, match

So, say I'm parsing the following HTML string:

```
<html>
    <head>
        RANDOM JAVASCRIPT AND CSS AHHHHHH!!!!!!!!
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table">
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="/subdir/members/Name">Name</a></tr>
        </table>
    <body>
</html>
```

and I want to isolate the contents of ****** (everything inside of the table class)

Now, I used regex to accomplish this:

```
string pagesource = (method that extracts the html source and stores it into a string);
string[] splitSource = Regex.Split(pagesource, "<table class=/"member/">;
string memberList = Regex.Split(splitSource[1], "</table>");
//the list of table members will be in memberList[0];
//method to extract links from the table
ExtractLinks(memberList[0]);
```

I've been looking at other ways to do this extraction, and I came across the Match object in C#.

I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(pageSource, "<table class=\"members\">(.|\n)*?</table>");
```

The purpose of the above was to **hopefully** extract a match value between the two delimiters, but, when I try to run it the match value is:

```
match.value = </table>
```

MY question, as such, is: is there a way to extract data from my string that is slightly easier/more readable/shorter than my method using regex? For this simple example, regex is fine, but for more complex examples, I find myself with the coding equivalent of scribbles all over my screen.

I would really like to use match, because it seems like a very neat and tidy class, but I can't seem to get it working for my needs. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: One small note: the portion of your regex between the two table tags should read `(.|\n)*?`.  If you don't put parenthesis around `.|\n`, then the `*?` will only apply to the character before it (\n in this case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: [Don't parse HTMl with regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: aren't you missing some `<td>` tags?

Comment: Yeah yeah, I typed the html up and wasn't paying attention =p.

Comment: Also, the class of your table does not match the class in your regex.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."([Jamie Zawinski](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an HTML parser, like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

using (var wc = new WebClient())
using (var stream = wc.OpenRead(url))
{
    doc.Load(stream);
}

var table = doc.DocumentElement.Element("html").Element("body").Element("table");
string tableHtml = table.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: I'm actually trying HTML agility pack, but the lack of documentation is terrifying! and the new downloadable doesn't have a chm, so, to find help, I'm basically looking through the manifest that came with the downloadable... all in all, it does not make for a friendly experience!

Comment: @gfppaste, there's no real need for documentation, the API is quite self-explanatory and very similar to Linq to XML. I learned to use it by using Intellisense, it's quite intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath with the HTmlAgilityPack:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(s);
var elements = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='table']");

foreach (var ele in elements)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ele.OuterHtml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have add parenthesis in the regular expression in order to capture the matches:

`Match match = Regex.Match(pageSource, "<table class=\"members\">(.|\n*?)</table>")`;

Anyways it seems that only Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex correctly.